# How to add animation when adding or removing an object - Fabricjs

Tags: jquery, animation, html5-canvas, fabricjs

I am using FabricJS for my image manipulation library. I want to know how to add animation to an object when it is added to / removed from canvas. I referred the site for samples. But I couldn't find much for simple animation (like small jump or fade in to get user attention).

Should I use object.animate for that? Will it work when the object is deleted? A sample code or source of reference will be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like fabricJS itself provides a couple of approaches for animations.  You can either use a timeout/interval and then modify things like that or you can use the animate function (for simple object properties) to do it.  For this sort of thing, I think that using the animate function is easier.

For example:

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas(...);
var rect = new fabric.Rect(...);

function startAnimation() {
    // If the object was removed, add it back
    if (rect.opacity === 0) {
        canvas.add(rect);
    }

    // Animate the opacity of the rectangle from 0 - 1 and back
    rect.animate('opacity', rect.opacity === 0 ? 1 : 0, {
        duration: 1000,
        onChange: canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas),
        onComplete: function() {
            // Once the animation is complete, remove the object
            if (rect.opacity === 0) {
                canvas.remove(rect);
            }
        },
        easing: fabric.util.ease['easeInQuad']
    });
}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qnwjs0aw/

fabricJS Docs: http://fabricjs.com/cross & http://fabricjs.com/animation-easing

Comment: Great Answer. Tried updating your fiddle for jump in effect. I couldn't get it to work. Am I missing something?

http://jsfiddle.net/qnwjs0aw/1/

Comment: First argument of animate should be the property name.  That should be it.